# Conversion between H.MMSS and decimal hours using float in C

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded

I am working on a couple of functions to convert between representing time in decimal hours
(2 hours and 30 minutes is 2.5 hours) and the H.MMSS format (where two and a half hours is 2.3000). I initially implemented the functions using doubles and everything worked fine. However, as my embedded project grew in size I ran out of flash memory and had to move to floats.

Here is my MWE to show the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float toHMS(float inputTime) {
    float hours = 0;
    float minutes = 0;
    float seconds = 0;
    // get integral part for the hours
    hours = (int)inputTime;
    // transform into decimal minutes
    inputTime -= hours;
    inputTime *= 60;
    // Get the minutes
    minutes = (int)inputTime;
    // Get the seconds
    inputTime -= minutes;
    seconds = (int)(100 * inputTime);
    return hours + minutes/100 + seconds/ 10000;
} 

float toHours (float inputTime) {
    float hours = 0;
    float minutes = 0;
    float seconds = 0;
    // get integral part for the hours
    hours = (int)inputTime;
    inputTime = 100 * (inputTime - hours);
    minutes = (int)inputTime;
    inputTime = inputTime - minutes;
    seconds = 100 * inputTime;
    // normalize to 60
    minutes = minutes / 60;
    seconds = seconds / 3600;
    return hours + minutes + seconds;
}

float toHours2 (float inputTime) {
    float hours = 0;
    float minutes = 0;
    float seconds = 0;
    // get integral part for the hours
    hours = (int)inputTime;
    inputTime = roundf(100 * (inputTime - hours));
    minutes = (int)inputTime;
    inputTime = inputTime - minutes;
    seconds = 100 * inputTime;
    // normalize to 60
    minutes = minutes / 60;
    seconds = seconds / 3600;
    return hours + minutes + seconds;
}

void main(void) {
    float hms = toHMS(2.5f);
    printf("toHMS(2.5f): %.9f\n", hms);
    printf("toHours(toHMS(2.5f)): %.9f\n", toHours(hms));
    printf("\n");
    printf("toHours(2.3f): %.9f\n", toHours(2.3f));
    printf("\n");
    printf("toHours2(2.3f): %.9f\n", toHours2(2.3f));
}
```

And the results:

```
toHMS(2.5f): 2.299999952
toHours(toHMS(2.5f)): 2.511111021

toHours(2.3f): 2.511111021

toHours2(2.3f): 2.500000000
```

It seems to me that the problem is in toHours() since 2.3 in a single precision float is 2.299999952. Adding the roundf() in toHours2() fixed the issue.

Is this the only fix that's needed or can there be other input numbers that would throw off the calculation? I'm struggling to find a solution and to prove to myself that it applies to all possible input numbers, not just 2.3f.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use floating-point types. There's just not enough precision to be able to to keep track of time (or money!). Fixed-precision or other custom types is the way to go. Perhaps even strings or arrays of integers or similar.

Comment: As a simple **short-term** possible workaround, use `double` instead of `float`? Unless you're on a very memory-constrained system, there's really no need for `float` these days.

Comment: Instead of `double` or `float`, how about scaled integers? But, while I get the fractional hours (e.g. `2.5`), I'm not sure I understand `2.3000`. The latter would be better as a string (e.g. `02:30:00`) or a 3 byte `char` array (e.g. `char HMS[3] = { 2, 30, 0 };`) It's just as easy [if not easier] to manipulate those than `double/float`. And, you don't have to worry about roundoff/truncation issues. If you're worried about memory, a 3 byte array is less space than a `double` or a `float`.

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Pretty sure that the solution to the underlying problem is to store the times as an integer number of seconds.

Comment: I agree that integers would work better, but I am trying to reproduce the functionality of an old HP calculator where the format is H.MMSS, not H:MM:SS. I moved to floats from doubles because since I am coding a calculator, I am using a lot of functions from the math library: csin, casin, csinh, casinh, et cetera. These simply take too much memory when I use doubles (I have 64kB of flash). Because the result of toHMS() goes on the calculator stack and can be used by other operations of the calculator, it has to be in the same float format, not an integer or a char array.

Comment: Even if you're emulating an old calculator, I doubt it used floating point for times. It might not even have used floating point numbers for numbers and numeric calculations. Can you please tell us the exact model of calculator you're trying to emulate?

Comment: I am writing a firmware for the swissmicros DM15L https://www.swissmicros.com/product/dm15l which is a replica of the HP15C with modern hardware.

Comment: IIRC, old calculators of that era used BCD (binary coded decimal) format (4 bits/digit) arithmetic. So, a byte holds two decimal digits. The chances of the old calculator using floating point format are very small. You might also want to look at: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `double` will not fix the problem, because the amount of precision is not the issue.

Comment: Forget about floating point here. The HP15C did not have an FPU, it used BCD arithmetic. The display was a 10-digit-7segment display, which did not support ':' but only '.' as separator. The DM15L does have an Cortex-M0, which also does not have an FPU. So, your reasons for using floating point does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toHours` fails because 2.30 is not representable in the format commonly used for `float`, IEEE-754 “single precision” (binary64). The nearest representable value is 2.2999999523162841796875. Your routine correctly returns the approximate decimal time for 2 hours, 29 minutes, and 99.999523162841796875 seconds, about 2.5111. But that is not how you want to interpret 2.2999999523162841796875; you want to interpret it as “2.3000”. More on how to do that below.

`toHours2` fails where it uses `roundf`. For input of `2.3050f`, it returns about 2.516666651 for 2 hours and 31 minutes, but the correct answer is about 2.513888836.

For reasonable amounts of time, you can implement `toHours` as:

```
float toHours(float inputTime)
{
    long t = lround(inputTime * 1e4);
    int seconds = t % 100;
    int minutes = t / 100 % 100;
    int hours   = t / 10000;
    return (seconds / 60. + minutes) / 60. + hours;
}
```

As long as the time has not grown too large and comes from a value with an integral number of seconds, `lround(inputTime * 1e4)` effectively recovers the digits, repairing the rounding that occurred in conversion to binary floating-point. Then the number can be taken apart using integer arithmetic. For times exceeding 1,024 hours, you may see rounding issues, because 1,024 is the point at which the binary32 format can no longer represent numbers less than .0001 apart (the spacing is 1,024/2<sup>23</sup>, which is about .000122), and you need that to distinguish seconds in an “H.MMSS” format.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation! Where is the 1677 hours limit come from? Also, should the toHMS() function be re-implemented with integer math like other solutions suggest, or is the problem solely in the toHours() implementation?

Comment: @Leo: The binary32 format has a 24-bit significand, so it can represent all integers up to 2^24, which is 16,777,216. Conversely, for numbers up to 1677.7216, it can represent numbers that are about .0001 apart. The actual boundary is 1024, up to which numbers can be represented less than .0001 apart. So rounding errors may affect results after 1024 hours. I will update the answer with that.

Comment: Note thar `lround(inputTime * 1e4);` uses `double` math, effectively removing 1 roundoff error, yet at the cost of wider math  Do you think `lroundf(inputTime * 1e4f);` would do noticeably  worse?

Answer (score 3):

> ... or can there be other input numbers that would throw off the calculation?

Yes.  And these come up due to repeated roundings.  Consider *hours* with the floating point value just below a whole number.

Instead, minimize roundings and perform most calculations with integer math.

To change `hours` into *H.MMSS*, scale, round, segment into H,M,S.

```
//Untested code

float toHMS(float inputTime) {
    long long t = llroundf(inputTime * 3600.0f);  // Rounded result
    int sec = t % 60;
    t /= 60;
    int min = t % 60;
    t /= 60;
    t = t * 10000 + min*100 + sec;
    return t/10000.0f; // 2nd Rounding
}
```

Similar code for `H.MMSS` into *hours*.

```
float toHours(float inputTime) {
    long long t = llroundf(inputTime * 10000.0f);  // Rounded result
    int sec = t % 100;
    t /= 100;
    int min = t % 100;
    t /= 100;
    t = t * 3600 + min*60 + sec;
    return t/3600.0f; // 2nd Rounding
}
```

Comment: Detail `llroundf(inputTime * 3600.0f);` is 2 roundings (product and conversion), yet rarely suffers from _double rounding_.

Comment: For those interested knowing more about [fixed point arithmetic](https://vanhunteradams.com/FixedPoint/FixedPoint.html)